# Javascript classList add and remove not working inside non global execution context

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a schematic on how an execution stack works on Javascript by creating a stack with 3 exec context. Global, executionA and executionB. For that I built a nested set of divs and added a displayNone class.

The functions should remove the displayNone class during it's runtime by using the classList.remove('displayNone') and after a setTimeout, insert the class again using classList.add('displayNone').

But for some reason, it's not working. If I take the classList commands to the global context it works properly.

Below the HTML:

```
<button onclick="a()">Run function a</button>
<br>

<div class="global displayNone">
  <p>Este bloco está aparecendo devido a função executada no global execution context que removeu a classe displayNone desta div</p>
  <div class="executionA displayNone">
    <p>Este bloco só vai aparecer durante a execução do execution context da função A.</p>
    <div class="executionB displayNone">
      <p>Este bloco só vai aparecer durante a execução do execution context da função B.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var content=document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
var globalDiv=document.getElementsByClassName('global')[0];
var execA=document.getElementsByClassName('executionA');
var execB=document.getElementsByClassName('executionB');

function rem(x){
  x[0].classList.remove('displayNone');
}
function add(x){
  x[0].classList.add('displayNone');
}


globalDiv.classList.remove('displayNone');
content.innerHTML="output results here";

function b(){
  content.innerHTML="function b executed";
rem(execB);
add(execB);
}

function a(){
  content.innerHTML="function a executed";
rem(execA);
  setTimeout(b,3000);
add(execA);
}
```

Here's the example on CodePen https://codepen.io/PierBotteroWeb/pen/OBmPPY?editors=1010

Answer (score 2):

It is working as it should, just not how you expect it. Just under `rem(execA)` and `rem(execB)` you have `add(execA)` and `add(execB)`, so effectively you remove and add class at the same time. That's why you don't see any changes on screen.

Wrap `add(execA)` and `add(execB)` in a `setTimeout()` and then see how it works.

Comment: mmm... just tried that on CodePen if you want to check. No deal yet.

Comment: You're using the same timeout 3000 for all 3 functions, so they all run at the same time.

Comment: @PierBottero Try `setTimeout(rem, 3000, execA); setTimeout(add, 6000, execA);`